# save() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, django

Calling LocationDescription.l_edit returns error "save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'location'". Keyword name looks random though and may point to different fields at different times. The method l_edit was stripped of functionality, but the error persists. Curiously, self.location = kwargs['location'] followed by self.save() works just fine.

models.py

```
class LocationDescription(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Localization)
    YEAR_CHOICES = (
        (LocationDescriptionYear.any.value, 'Any'),
        (LocationDescriptionYear.winter.value, 'Winter'),
        (LocationDescriptionYear.spring.value, 'Spring'),
        (LocationDescriptionYear.summer.value, 'Summer'),
        (LocationDescriptionYear.autumn.value, 'Autumn'),
    )
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=0)
    DAY_CHOICES = (
        (LocationDescriptionDaytime.any.value, 'Any'),
        (LocationDescriptionDaytime.night.value, 'Night'),
        (LocationDescriptionDaytime.morning.value, 'Morning'),
        (LocationDescriptionDaytime.day.value, 'Day'),
        (LocationDescriptionDaytime.evening.value, 'Evening'),
    )
    day = models.IntegerField(choices=DAY_CHOICES, default=0)
    weather_type = models.ForeignKey('Weather', blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    code_check = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    @classmethod
    def l_create(cls, request, **kwargs):
        l = Localization()
        l.write(request, kwargs['description'])
        kwargs['description'] = l
        item = cls(**kwargs)
        item.save()
        return item

    def l_delete(self):
        l = self.description
        self.delete()
        l.delete()

    def l_edit(self, **kwargs):
        super(LocationDescription, self).save(**kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def localize(cls, locale, **kwargs):
        if locale == 'eng':
            result = cls.objects.filter(**kwargs).annotate(text=F('description__eng'))
        elif locale == 'rus':
            result = cls.objects.filter(**kwargs).annotate(text=F('description__rus'))
        else:
            raise KeyError
        for r in result:
            if r.text is None or r.text == '':
                setattr(r, 'text', 'Error: localization text missing!')
        return result
```

views.py

```
            location = Location.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('location', '')))
            weather_type = Weather.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('weather_type', '')))
            item = LocationDescription.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('id', '')))
            item.l_edit(location=location,
                        year=request.POST.get('year', ''),
                    day=request.POST.get('day', ''),
                    weather_type=weather_type,
                    order=request.POST.get('order', ''),
                    code_check=request.POST.get('code_check', ''),
                    )
```

Comment: Well, it's because save doesn't indeed take field arguments. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: Because I have no idea what I am doing :) I'll have to read the examples once again I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`save` does not require those named arguments you're passing. Besides, since you're not overriding the default `save` method I don't see the need for `super`.

You can simply set those attributes on that instance of your model and call `save` like would with a model object:

```
def l_edit(self, **kwargs):
    for k in kwargs:
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
    self.save()
```

On a side note, using [`update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#update) is more efficient than your current approach if you don't need to have the `item` in memory.

Comment: Thank you, Captain. I knew I was asking a dumb question, but I was desperate enough to reach the second page of Google and just started feeling I had no understanding of something very basic.